LogAnalytics KQL query to identify column size within a table
I was wondering if there was a KQL query for retrieving the size of a column like "ConditionalAccessPolicies" within the AADNonInteractiveUserSignInLogs table?
The query below shows the overall billable size of the table for the period of time I specify, but I would like it to be broken down further so that I can identify which columns, if any, are contributing significantly to the total, and from there, determine if any can be filtered out prior to ingestion.
"union withsource=table AADNonInteractiveUserSignInLogs | summarize Size = sum(_BilledSize) by table, _IsBillable | sort by Size desc
| extend Size2 = format_bytes(Size, 2)"

for estimating the data size of specific columns, you can use the estimate_date_size() function
